# How to use sugar.js with CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, casperjs, sugar.js

To be clear, I want to use [sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com) extensions in my casperJS script (as distinct from it being part of the web site being tested).

I am using casperJS in test mode (i.e. `casperjs test myscript.js`) if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugar is basically a support library. It does not export any function, but adds functions to the various types of objects of a JavaScript runtime.

Steps:

1. Place [sugar.min.js](http://sugarjs.com/release/current/sugar.min.js) in the script directory or some other directory,
2. `require("sugar.min");` to execute the file directly or from another directory `require("./relativePath/sugar.min");`.

The following complete script shows that it works:

```
casper.test.begin("sugar1", function suite(test){
    test.assertTrue(![1,2,3].average, "average function does not exist");
    require("sugar.min");
    test.assertFalse(![1,2,3].average, "average function does exist");
    test.assertTrue([1,2,3].average() === 2, "average function works");
    test.done();
});
```

`require` is usually for loading modules, but since Sugar does not export anything it is just executed. An alternative would be reading the file with `fs.read` and `eval`.

Comment: Perfect! And easier than I realized. (I used `require` with a relative path, and it worked first time.)

Comment: `require` is quite the work horse. If you require a JSON file it is directly parsed and exported.

Comment: Artjom, I switched from using `require` to `fs.read()` and `eval`; see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Just an addendum to Artjom's answer; when using SlimerJS as the engine it hangs when using `require`. I got it working (with both PhantomJS and SlimerJS) using the following:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sugarJS = fs.read("/path/to/sugar.min.js");
eval(sugarJS);
```

as a drop-in replacement for:

```
require("/path/to/sugar.min");
```